# Use of a function in the Where clause in linq-to-sql in an ASP.Net MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have the following code in an ASP.Net MVC 4 application with Linq-to-SQL.

```
private bool isFallInCurrentSeason(DateTime? dt)
{
  if ({condition})
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

public IQueryable<T> FindByLocId(int locId)
{
  var records = from l in db.Ts
                  where (l.LocationId == locId)
                  where ((l.ObservationStatus == 0) || isFallInCurrentSeason(l.FinalisedDate.value))
                  orderby l.ObservationId
                  select l;

  return records;
}
```

When I debugged the code in MS Web Developer 2010 Express, it threw out the following error message:

```
Method 'Boolean isFallInCurrentSeason(DateTime? dt)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Can anybody give me an idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Cheers, Alex

Comment: I wanted to make a function reusable so that I can use it in other query functions.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL tried to transform your query to SQL. It works based on Expression Trees. LINQ to SQL query provider has no idea how to transform a method call to your method into proper SQL text, and that's why you're getting an exception.

You should inline your condition in the query (to let compiler generate proper Expression Tree generation code).